# set the default authentication to IsAuthenticated in settings.py globally but I can still access the endpoints in django rest framework

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I have set the default authentication class to IsAuthenticated  globally in settings.py file but still, I can still access the endpoints. what could be the issue? Below are the Django rest frameworks' configs in settings.py file.

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSESS': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'liquor.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication',
    ),

    'DEFAULT_SCHEMA_CLASS': 'rest_framework.schemas.coreapi.AutoSchema',
    'DEFAULT_PARSER_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.parsers.FormParser',
        'rest_framework.parsers.MultiPartParser',
        'rest_framework.parsers.JSONParser',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS': ['django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend'],
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.PageNumberPagination',
    'PAGE_SIZE':100,
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSESS': (
        'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
        'rest_framework.renderers.BrowsableAPIRenderer',
    ),

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spelling mistake in `DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSESS` it should be `DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES`